# windows vs ubuntu NameError: global name is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Hi please can someone help. I have a ubuntu server(python 2.7.12) and a windows server(python 2.7.13). The code below runs perfectly on the ubuntu box however i receive an error on windows server.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

check="h"

def run(check):
    return test.validityCheck(check)

class t:

    def validityCheck(self,check):
        time.sleep(4)
        print(check)
        errorStatus=str("error")
        return ("error state: "+errorStatus)

    def valid(self,check):
        print 'starting....'
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)
        res = pool.apply_async(run, [check])
        try:
            print res.get(timeout=5)
        except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
            error=1
        print 'end'

    def valid1(self, check):
        self.valid(check)

if __name__=='__main__':
    test=t()
    test.valid1(check)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:/scripts/m1.py", line 32, in 
>       test.valid1(check)
>    File "C:/scripts/m1.py", line 28, in valid1
>       self.valid(check)
>    File "C:/scripts/m1.py", line 22, in valid
>       print res.get(timeout=5)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
>       raise self._value
>   NameError: global name 'test' is not defined

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: hi added traceback

Comment: Look at your `run` function. You have not defined the object "test" anywhere, so the error message says "NameError: global name 'test' is not defined"

Comment: it works in windows if i remove  __name__=='__main__':

Comment: its defined at the bottom before the run function gets called

Comment: when using multiprocessing library, the parallel task will be executed from another python process. Only objects passed as arguments to `run` function will be accessible, not the global ones.

Comment: @Nikazo any idea why it would still work on a Linux environment though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `test` variable isn't defined when your script spawns another process and executes the `run` function. Your `test` variable was only set when the `__name__` variable set as `"__main__"`. The interpreter changes the `__name__` value to `"__parents_main__"` in a spawned process so `test` won't be defined. As you figured out, removing the if statement sets the variable since that is no longer contingent on `__name__` being set to `'__main__'` but as pointed out in the comments below, this will lead to self-replicating worker threads and lead to errors.

Add:

```
if __name__=='__main__' or __name__=='__parents_main__':
    test=t()
# Updated as per comments below. Only run this function in the original process,
# not a spawned worker thread
if __name__=='main':
    test.valid1(check)
```

to your code and it will work fine. You could also just define `test` outside the bottom `if __name__=='main'` conditional and have the same effect.

Comment: thanks you a legend my friend.. saved me lots of fustration

Comment: Glad I could help! Hope I can update the answer in a bit to give a bit more info as to the 'why' this happens.

Comment: This is going to have the worker processes also execute `valid1`, generating more workers that will also execute `valid1` and generate more workers and so on.

Comment: how do i stop that from happening

Comment: If you have `test.valid1` function only execute in the main script process, i.e. only if `__name__` is `__main__` and not `__parents_main__` does that give you the correct behavior?